# Limit of $x^ny^n$ when $n \to \infty$

Tags: limits

Please, someone could help me in solving the following limit.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Also consider that $0<x<1$ and $1<y<\infty$.

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}x^ny^n = L $$.

What is the value of $L$ ?

Comment: $x^ny^n=\left(xy\right)^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^ny^n = (xy)^n$$

If $xy<1$ , Limit = $0$

If $xy=1$, Limit = 1

If $xy>1$, Limit $\to \infty$

Answer (score -3):

$L=\infty$ since the function is in form $\frac{\infty}{0}$ where $n\to \infty$

Comment: you neglected the case xy<1